# How to create a popup in UWP

Tags: uwp, popup, desktop

I'm trying to make a desktop application with Width= 600 Height=500.
How to create a popup dialog that overlaps complete window of the app?
When the user clicks on Terms&Condition (within mainpage) I want to popup a dialog like [this](https://ibb.co/b92VkU)?

Comment: To solve this you can use the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.contentdialog

Answer (score 4):

You can create a [ContentDialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.contentdialog) or [MessageDialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.popups.messagedialog)

**ContentDialog Example**

```
ContentDialog noWifiDialog = new ContentDialog()
{
    Title = "No wifi connection",
    Content = "Check connection and try again.",
    CloseButtonText = "Ok"
};

await noWifiDialog.ShowAsync();
```

Comment: How to apply my custom style if I made him in XAML already? I'm new in programming and pretty bad in c#.

Comment: @AndrianPirlici if you are bad in c# first you need to get you basic c# skills only then you should try to make uwp apps.

Comment: but anyways you can se how to create custom content dialogs and add any xaml to them in the docs link already provided in the answer just click on "ContentDialog" link in the answer above.

Comment: What method I should use in my c# code to apply my template? I have one template in xaml code with x:key ="style1" and even a file in Assets/joricstyle.xaml with same x:key.
My c# code right now is 
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {         
            ContentDialog dialog = new ContentDialog()
            {        
            };              
            await dialog.ShowAsync();
        }
But it show an emtry contentdialog.

Comment: you dont need a custom style with x:key, just visit the docs link I provided creating custom content dialog is like creating a user control you right click project -> add new item -> contentDialog.

Comment: it's possible to change in a new created ContentDialog position of buttons and style of scroll without editing template of contentDialog? I'm already tired 4 searching tutorials that not only create in c# a simple content dialog .

Comment: no it is not possible to change the button positions without editing the template, but you can hide the buttons and creat your own custom content in the dialog if you just follow the instruction I have been repeatedly telling you, if you already had a look at the docs you will not need to ask me this :)

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to your XAML code.

```
<Popup x:Name="Nav_Pop" 
        IsOpen="False" 
        Width="750" 
        Height="700" 
        IsLightDismissEnabled="True"
        VerticalOffset="10"
        HorizontalOffset="200"
        VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        LightDismissOverlayMode="On">
</Popup>
```

**Note:**
Set the `IsLightDismissEnabled` Property to `True` to dismiss the popup by clicking anywhere on the app.

Inside the popup tags, you can add required child elements.

Answer (score 0):

Till the end I make a New ContentDialog (Add>NewItem>ContentDialog1).
 After in ContentDialog1.xaml I paste defaul style of ContentDialog inside of    and in MainPage.xaml.cs I instatiate this dialog and show him after with this code:
 " ContentDialog1 dialog = new ContentDialog1();
   await dialog.ShowAsync();".

But now problem is that this dialog is inside of my frame. How can I overlay this dialog on application ?